# How to use forEach to populate HTML elements

Tags: javascript, foreach

How would I use `forEach` to populate HTML elements?  In my simple example below I'm trying to populate each `DIV` with the counter "increment".  I'm using `this.innerHTML` to target each innerHTML in the array.  I know I'm missing something but I can't see it.

```js
var myArray = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
 
myArray = Array.from(myArray);
 
myArray.forEach( (item, increment) => this.innerHTML = increment );
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: arial;
    color: white;
}
 
.box {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Did you mean `item.innerHTML = increment`?

Comment: Swap `this` to `item`, as you declare `item` variable for each array element.

Comment: [`arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {}[, thisArg]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): _"If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `forEach()`, it will be used as callback's `this` value.  Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be used as its this value. The `this` value ultimately observable by `callback` is determined according to the [usual rules for determining the this seen by a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` is passing `item` and `increment` as parameters.

`this` does not refer to your `item` but to the global window in this scope. You can set the `item.innerHTML` by using the `item` parameter.

```js
var myArray = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
 
myArray = Array.from(myArray);
 
myArray.forEach( (item, increment) =>  item.innerHTML = increment} );
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: arial;
    color: white;
}
 
.box {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Was in the middle of doing so.

Comment: That was exactly it.  Fixed on the spot.  Was `this.innerHTML` pointing at anything at all?

Comment: @DR01D [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

This code will work:
when using forEach, the item in the array is the first argument. "this" is the window in this context.

```
var myArray = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
var arr = Array.from(myArray)
arr.forEach((item,counter)=>(item.innerHTML = counter))
```